# I am facing Curl 6 error in CI Project Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, razorpay

I am trying to integrate razor pay in my CI project but it give me error of "**cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: api.razorpay.com**" and i have ubuntu server with Enable cURL, cURL Information :  7.68.0 what is the issue i didn't find it.

Comment: Are you getting this on your local machine or on server? 

as per the error it looks like it's either network issue or the website is blocked on that network.

Comment: try telnet at the host and check either you have network access over that host or not.

Comment: In my local machine its working fine but in server its give me error and how to unblock website can you give me a idea?

Comment: Please run this command on your server and share response "telnet api.razorpay.com 443"

if you are using https://api.razorpay.com in your code if it's http://api.razorpay.com then use port 80 instead of 443

Comment: Response  : telnet: could not resolve api.razorpay.com:80/telnet: Name or service not known i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 :
Please check /etc/hosts file on server and see if any record found for api.razorpay.com

remove that record so it can fetch from DNS service provider.

Step 2:
if not work you can add your record into your hosts file but it's not a permanent  solution as Server IP can be change

```
13.234.70.181   api.razorpay.com
```